# Alignment and hyphenation issues

Tags: xetex, luatex, hyphenation, alignment, ragged2e

Can we use \! and ~ to adjust the space between the words to adjust the hyphenation and the readability of the paragraph?

Comment: you can, but `\!`  would be rather rare and `~` is the same space as a normal space, so it's adjusting linebreaking rather than space between words.

Comment: Yeah I want to avoid hyphenation at certain places so I adjust by these two commands. Is there any alternative way to adjust the line breaking in professional way

Comment: se for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661347/justified-text-extending-beyond-margin-and-i-cant-hyphenate

Comment: In addition to the tactics shown in the question cited by @DavidCarlisle, if your main goal is to suppress hyphenation, you can wrap the word that isn't to be hyphenated in an `\mbox` or (if you never want a particular word hyphenated, or hyphenated differently) you can add a `\hyphenation` entry in your preamble; see [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571).

Answer (score 0):

There are two general modes for the behaviour of the engine regarding hyphenation.

Two commands are available:

- `\sloppy` and `\fussy`.
- `\fussy` is the default.

If you think you get too many hyphenations, try `\sloppy`, which makes the program much more tolerant, i.e. more reluctant to hyphenating.

You may also play with other parameters such as:
`\hyphenpenalty=<number>`

I personally hate hyphenation, and find the following settings to give the best results
(cf. [Apply hyphenation to words containing dashes only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463147/apply-hyphenation-to-words-containing-dashes-only/463197#463197)):

```
\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty=9999
```

Of course, many will disagree: it's a subjective matter.

For technical details, see this post:
[What is the meaning of \fussy, \sloppy, \emergencystretch, \tolerance, \hbadness?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness)