# Justified text extending beyond margin, and I can't hyphenate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

So I have the following snippet from a project I'm working on. The first line of the second paragraph extends beyond the right hand margin rather than being flush with the right side.

Other answers suggest hyphenation to solve this, but I can't hyphenate it as it is a single syllable word. Is there anything I can do to sort this out?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,
  paperheight=8.5in,
  inner=0.25in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bindingoffset=0.25in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Now the merchant-farmer understood what all this meant, because he had overheard the talk between the Bull and the Ass, so quoth he, ``Take that rascal donkey, and set the yoke on his neck, and bind him to the plough and make him do Bull’s work.''

Thereupon the ploughman took the Ass, and worked him through the livelong day at the Bull’s task; and, when he failed for weakness, he made him eat stick till his ribs were sore and his sides were sunken and his neck was flayed by the yoke; and when he came home in the evening he could hardly drag his limbs along, either
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, given the relatively big font for the line width, you can use `\sloppy` for the paragraph:

```latex
...

{\sloppy
Thereupon the ploughman took the Ass, and worked him through the livelong day at the Bull’s task; and, when he failed for weakness, he made him eat stick till his ribs were sore and his sides were sunken and his neck was flayed by the yoke; and when he came home in the evening he could hardly drag his limbs along, either

}
% notice the white line above, \sloppy is applied when \par is found.
...
```

[image]

The line is effectively a bit sloppy, yes...

If you use `microtype` (add `\usepackage{microtype}` in your preamble), you still have an overfull line, but it's:

```
Overfull \hbox (1.02644pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
```

which maybe it's acceptable.

[image]

Finally, you can reduce the indentation at the start of the paragraphs; for example `\parindent=14pt` with microtype will fix the overfull line.

```latex
%! TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,
  paperheight=8.5in,
  inner=0.25in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bindingoffset=0.25in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\parindent=14pt

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Now the merchant-farmer understood what all this meant, because he had overheard the talk between the Bull and the Ass, so quoth he, ``Take that rascal donkey, and set the yoke on his neck, and bind him to the plough and make him do Bull’s work.''

Thereupon the ploughman took the Ass, and worked him through the livelong day at the Bull’s task; and, when he failed for weakness, he made him eat stick till his ribs were sore and his sides were sunken and his neck was flayed by the yoke; and when he came home in the evening he could hardly drag his limbs along, either

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh you'd already suggested microtype, I'll delete:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no need to delete... and `sloppypar` it's better than `{\sloppy   \par}`, really...

Comment: mine doesn't add anything, it's gone:-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably use the \sloppy command. It doesn't look as bad as having a single line stand out, and reducing the indent may work for this, but the problem could still arise for another line.

Comment: After researching the command a bit, I've also come across `\emergencystretch`, which I think is preferable. I've set it to `3em` in my preamble, and it's fixed this issue throughout the document.